# How to use Sentry in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, domdocument, sentry, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to use Sentry in a chrome extension project. Here is a [workaround](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/5289#issuecomment-1368705821).

If I try this code in background.js file:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser'

Sentry.WINDOW.document = {
  visibilityState: 'hidden',
  addEventListener: () => {},
}
```

I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot set property document of #<Window> which has only a getter`

I tried to update code to this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Sentry.WINDOW, 'document', {
  value: {
    visibilityState: 'hidden',
    addEventListener: () => {},
  },
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
})
```

but now I am getting error: `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: document`.

Any ideas how can I fix this and use Sentry in a browser extension?

Comment: have you tried copying Sentry file content to the script and calling that script from manifest.json?

Comment: @AzizaKasenova what do you mean by calling script from manifest.json?

Comment: copying content of sentry codes to some file (like sentry.js), include that file to your project and define it in `manifest.json` like other JS files in your extension

Comment: @Matt what kind of bundler do you use? It would be very helpful if you would create a sample public repo.

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev your comment helped me to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue. The key is to don't import anything from background.js into content script.

In my case the whole file background.js was called in my content script, because I imported a variable. For this reason whole background.js was called in content script:

```
Sentry.WINDOW.document = {
  visibilityState: 'hidden',
  addEventListener: () => {},
}
```

When I moved the variable from background.js to my content script file, I got rid off the error because background.js is called only in service worker now.